# Is my manager allowed to tell me to stay behind until I finish something?

Tags: work-time, australia, law

If I am rostered until, say, 9pm. Is my manager allowed to tell me that I need to complete something (clean something, do this, etc.) before I am allowed to leave, even when it is past my rostered finish time?

If they say I need to ask 15 minutes before my shift ends, do I actually need to do this, or should they be the ones that should tell me to do something before my shift ends without me asking?

Comment: Any time spent working (whether it's "to finish something" or "until some time") outside of your shift would be considered overtime. Whether your manager is allowed to force you to do overtime or whether you need to get paid for it will depend on your contract and local laws. As for doing what your boss tells you to do within your working hours - if you want to keep your job, yes, you need to do that, the answer is always yes (within legal limits).

Comment: Interesting question since I have zero knowledge of how Australia handles this. You'll need someone with experience with their labour laws to chime in for an answer, but could you add whether there are any specifics to your contract that might impact the answer? Things like whether you are part-time, are eligible for / allowed to do over-time, etc.

Comment: @Lilienthal When says if “x is allowed” isn’t this another way of saying “is it legal”?

Comment: Is it not possible to make time to do whatever was asked before you leave, but still leave on time? For example, "clean the kitchen area before you leave" could be achieved by saying to yourself "I'm going to clean the kitchen area half an hour before my shift ends, and then resume working for the remaining time so I can leave on time."

Comment: @FrankFYC Yes but as per the [main thread on it on meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice) these specific legal questions have been identified as on-topic. Any HR person or business owner active in Australia should be able to answer this.

Comment: In your last statement, are you saying that 15 minutes prior to leaving, you're required to ask your manager if there are any extra work?

Answer (score 3):

This would strongly depend on your specific contract and what you agreed on it.

Usually you are hired to fulfill a fixed amount of hours a day, which you have to complete before retiring for the day. **If you have already fulfilled those hours any more time spent working should be considered overtime and paid accordingly.**

In other situations it may be more tricky, like in the cases where your contract specifies a number of tasks or tickets you should complete by the end of the day. In some cases you may quickly finish them, while other times they may take longer. However, **IANAL but in these cases there probably is a law or regulation specifying a maximum number of hours per day**, regardless of the tickets you have.

> If they say I need to ask 15 minutes before my shift ends, do I actually need to do this, or should they be the ones that should tell me to do something before my shift ends without me asking?

I am not familiar with your contract, but what I understood here is that you should notify 15 minutes before shift ends if you still have a task rostered that needs completion, so they may consider it.

Again, I suggest you check your contract or well include more details of it in your question.

Answer (score 3):

In Australia, your job responsibilities and rights are covered by the award or agreement you signed when you started. There are minimum rules for all workers under FairWork, but these are expanded on in the specific award or agreement. Giving what you write in your question, I would expect you to be on an award specific to shift workers in either retail or hospitality (covers restaurants and hotels/pubs) - I'm not 100% but I think any requirement to work beyond agreed hours should be overtime and paid back as such or as TOIL (additional leave provided at 1:1 ratio - sometimes can be provided at 1.5 or even double time).

In general, the advice at https://www.fairwork.gov.au/pay/penalty-rates-and-allowances/overtime-pay applies - but you will have to check your award, too. For example, I'm on a professional worker award, so even though I have a 7.5 hour day, there's an expectation to work a "reasonable additional time" in my award.

Comment: Does award = contract?

Comment: @frankfyc Award is kind of like a contract, but is drafted by the government for a specific kind of job/industry. The idea being is all retail staff across Australia are on the same award, for example. There's leeway for specifics like hours and money, but standardised role/responsibilities and things like overtime penalties. AFAIK it's a uniquely Australian thing.

Comment: Sounds like collective bargaining in the US but on a national level?

Comment: @FrankFYC Yeah - it's meant to replace collective bargaining - but it's also voluntary for the employer. However, it's pretty standard to follow awards.